# save state checkbox

Tags: java, android

Помогите с сохранением состояния `CheckBox`.

```
 @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_gridview, null);

        }
        @Override
        public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
loadSavedPreferences();
            setList();

        }

        private void setList() {
            try {
                mListView = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(android.R.id.list);

                check = (CheckBox) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.check);
                if(check.isChecked()) {
                    savePreferences("CheckBox_Value", check.isChecked());

                });

                setListAdapter(new CustomListAdapterVisualStudio(getActivity(), R.layout.listview_gridview, itemname, imgid));
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, ex.getMessage());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
            //  Fragment fragment = null;
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                   break; 
            }
        }

        public class CustomListAdapterVisualStudio extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
            private final Activity context;
            private final Integer layout;
            private final String[] itemname;
            private final Integer[] imgid;

            class ViewHolder {
                public TextView txtTitle, extratxt;
                public CheckBox check;
                public ImageView imageView;
            }

            public CustomListAdapterVisualStudio(Activity context, Integer layout, String[] itemname, Integer[] imgid) {
                super(context, R.layout.listview_item, itemname);

                // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
                this.context=context;
                this.layout = layout;
                this.itemname=itemname;
                this.imgid=imgid;
            }
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                View view = convertView;
                if (view == null) {
                    LayoutInflater inflator = context.getLayoutInflater();
                    view = inflator.inflate(R.layout.listview_item, null);
                    final ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

                    viewHolder.txtTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item);
                    viewHolder.imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.icon);
                    viewHolder.extratxt = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                    viewHolder.check = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.check);
                    viewHolder.check.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                            if (viewHolder.check.isChecked()) {
                                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Добавлена закладка", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Закладка удалена", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        }
                    });

                    viewHolder.txtTitle.setText(itemname[position]);
                    viewHolder.imageView.setImageResource(imgid[position]);
                    viewHolder.extratxt.setText(" Описание: " + opisanie[position]);
            }
                return view;
            }}


        private void loadSavedPreferences() {
            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager
                    .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
            boolean checkBoxValue = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("CheckBox_Value", false);
            if (checkBoxValue) {
                check.setChecked(true);
            } else {
                check.setChecked(false);
            }
        }

        private void savePreferences(String key, boolean value) {
            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager
                    .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
            editor.putBoolean(key, value);
            editor.commit();
        }
```

Получаю 2 ошибки - на `loadSavedPreferences()`  и на `check.setChecked(false)`.

стектрейс:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.CheckBox.setChecked(boolean)' on a null object reference
            at by.sviter.allbestlessons.listadapter.MainListVisualStudio.loadSavedPreferences(MainListVisualStudio.java:377)
            at by.sviter.allbestlessons.listadapter.MainListVisualStudio.onCreateView(MainListVisualStudio.java:107)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1786)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:953)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1136)
            at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:739)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1499)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:488)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:163)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1073)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:919)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1441)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
loadSavedPreferences();
```

в котором вы используете `check` вызывается раньше, чем

```
setList();
```

в котором вы какраз и инициализируете `check`
Вот и выходит, что используется переменная, в которой пока записан null раньше, чем в нее записывается объект

Comment: неподскажите новичку как быть?

Comment: @sviter-pro, попробуйте для начала просто поменять местами loadSavedPreferences();
            setList();

Comment: не помогает! те же ошибки

Comment: @sviter-pro, я вам показал, где ошибка. Как исправить уж думайте сами.